# Parameterise Spring Value annotation string

Tags: java, spring

If we have an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractSomeClass{
    private String type;
    private int someValue;
}
```

And each extending class had a value for type, such as:

```
public class SomeClassImpl extends AbstractSomeClass{
    {
        type = "someType";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use this value as a parameter for the Value annotation in a manner similar to this, although not exactly since the following produces the error "Attribute value must be constant":

```
@Value("${someClass." + type + ".someValue")
public void setSomeValue(int someValue){//...}
```

Such that we do not need to have the value annotation and an override of the setSomeValue method in each subclass?

Comment: values passed to an annotation can't be variable

Comment: It's not impossible to leverage Spring Expression Language to do the equivalent in your Value annotations, but I think it would be easier to just build your objects by injecting the Environment and read the properties dynamically from it.